# gasp doesent work on safari

Tags: jquery, safari, gsap, scrollmagic, gasp

anyone help me why this doesen't wrok on safari? it works great on chrome. the js script works on firefox also but with some svg problems which doesnt appear in their right position but thats another issue... in safari in the debugger tab i get this:

[image]

http://codepen.io/Separator/pen/dGEdeP

below is my js code using GASP

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {



    // define the main controller for ScrollMagic (note we can have multiple controllers if needed)
    controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
        globalSceneOptions: {

            triggerHook: 0
        }
    });



    // animacionet e perseritura pas hyrjes/////////////////////////////

    var tweensaturni = TweenMax.to("#saturni", 100, {rotation: 360, ease: Linear.easeOut, transformOrigin:'50% 50%', repeat:-1,force3D:true})

    var tweenplutoni = TweenMax.to("#plutoni", 30, {rotation: 360, ease: Linear.easeOut, transformOrigin:'50% 50%', repeat:-1,force3D:true})

    var tweenraketa = TweenMax.to("#raketa", 0.05, {y:'+=4',
  repeat:-1, yoyo:true,force3D:true})

    var tweenzjarri = TweenMax.to(".st2", 0.1, {scale:0.8,
  repeat:-1,force3D:true})


    var tweensateliti = TweenMax.to("#sateliti", 20, { rotation:360,
  transformOrigin:'50% 150%', repeat:-1,force3D:true} )
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// start a new ScrollMagic scene by calling the provided method from the ScrollMagic Class
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#komplet',
    duration: '800%'//(duration - window.innerHeight)
})

.setTween(new TimelineMax().add([



    // animacionet e hyrjeve


    TweenMax.staggerTo('#yjet', 5, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut}, 5),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#sateliti', 1, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:1, y:-100,force3D:true}, 0.15),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#saturni', 1, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:2, y:-100,force3D:true}, 0.15),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#plutoni', 1, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:3, y:-100,force3D:true}, 0.15),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#raketa', 1, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:4, x:-200,force3D:true}, 0.15),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#text1', 3, {autoAlpha: 1, force3D:true, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:5, y:-50}, 0.15),
    TweenMax.staggerTo('#text2', 3, {autoAlpha: 1, force3D:true, ease: Back.easeOut, delay:5, y:-50}, 0.15)
 ]))

.setPin("#komplet")


.addIndicators({name:'sdklfjsdf'})


.addTo(controller);


    ////////////// SHKRIMI









    function pathPrepare ($el) {
        var lineLength = $el[0].getTotalLength();
        $el.css("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
        $el.css("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
    }

    var $shkrimi = $("path#shkrimi");
    var $vija = $("path#vija");


    // prepare SVG
    pathPrepare($shkrimi);
    pathPrepare($vija);




    var tweenshkrimi = new TimelineMax()
        .add(TweenMax.to($shkrimi, 0.9, {strokeDashoffset: 3450, ease:Linear.easeNone,force3D:true})) 
        .add(TweenMax.to($vija, 0.1, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone,force3D:true}))  
        //.add(TweenMax.to("#pluto", 1, {stroke: "#fff", ease:Linear.easeNone}), 0);            

    // build scene
    var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#pluto", duration: 5400, tweenChanges: true})
                    .setTween(tweenshkrimi)
                    .setPin("#pluto")
                    .addTo(scene2)
                    .addIndicators({name:"shkrimi"}) 
                    .addTo(controller);



    /////////////////Pjesa2 //////////////////////




     controller2 = new ScrollMagic.Controller({

    });




    var tweensaturni2 = TweenMax.to("#saturni2", 10, {rotation: 360, ease: Linear.easeOut, transformOrigin:'50% 50%', repeat:-1,force3D:true})

    var tweenastronaut1 = TweenMax.to("#astronaut1", 50, {rotation: 360, ease: Linear.easeOut, transformOrigin:'50% 70%', repeat:-1,force3D:true})

    var tweenastronaut2 = TweenMax.to("#astronaut2", 80, {rotation:'360_ccw', ease: Linear.easeOut, transformOrigin:'50% 100%', repeat:-1,force3D:true,})





    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#pjesa2',
    duration: $('#pjesa2').height(),

        triggerHook:'onLeave', offset:300, reverse: true,
})

.setTween(new TimelineMax().add([


    TweenMax.to('body', 1, {backgroundColor: '#41c4b2'}), 

        TweenMax.staggerTo('#saturni2', 0.3, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Back.easeOut, y:-100, force3D:true,}, 1),
        TweenMax.staggerTo('#astromjegullat', 0.3, {autoAlpha: 1, delay:0.1, ease: Back.easeOut, y:-200, x:-100, scale:'0.8%', force3D:true,}, 1),

        TweenMax.staggerTo('#astronaut1', 0.3, {autoAlpha: 1, delay:0.2, ease: Back.easeOut, y:-100, x:100, scale:'0.8%', force3D:true,}, 1),

        TweenMax.staggerTo('#astronaut2', 0.3, {autoAlpha: 1, delay:0.3, ease: Back.easeOut, y:-150, x:0, scale:'0.8%', force3D:true,}, 1),

    ]))
    .setPin("#pjesa2")

   .addIndicators({name:'pjesa2'})


.addTo(controller2); 




    });
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome either. That is because you have a console error. You are calling `addTo()` which is not a valid ScrollMagic controller `12:37:17:945 (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR: supplied argument of 'addTo()' is not a valid ScrollMagic Controller`

Comment: how come? it works perfectly fine for me on chrome. as per the 'addTo()' below is a screenshot from the official scroll magic examples page and they use 'addTo()' as well: http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab210/batterylove/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-07%20at%2023.34.04.png

Comment: I tested on Windows 7 (64-bit) on latest Chrome, Firefox and IE11 .. The error I see in the console is coming from the ScrollMagic script your using!

Comment: You can always submit a bug report isssue to Jan Paepke who made the ScrollMagic plugin https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic

Comment: yah i did that. thnx for the interest, anyway im not working on this project anymore. my new projects work just fine but i dont know why this one didnt work. nevermind... thnx again